# ERWin Data Modeler forward engineer to multiple files

Tags: database-design, ddl, erwin

Is is possible to forward engineer a data model to multiple files? 
For example, a data model has 10 table, I would like one file per object; 
so 10 files instead of one.

I think we are on version 9.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible,You can do forward engineering of each table seperately.
Select the table and click on forward engineer, it will only generate script for one table and you can save the script.
or 
Click on Forward engineer, Select Filter on bottom left, then choose the Table from Table Pool.
Refer the image as below. 
[image: Forward Engineer - Table Filter]

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a copy of erwin available so I can't lead you through this step by step.

When you forward engineer, you get a selection screen (I think it is the second one in the series) where you can check and uncheck the objects in the model that you want included.

N.B. I believe that constraints will not be built where you have a relation to a table that is not included.